# Fail to run simple SQL queries on my Wordpress-database (downloading a website to a localhost)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, mysql-workbench

I want to download my website to my localhost and I am having trouble running simple queries on my Wordpress database so it would change all the "real" website URLs in the database to `"http://localhost"`  (following this tutorial (second part: downloading a wordpress website without using a plugin- http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/).

I downloaded all my website files from the FTP server to my localhost directory and downloaded my database (zipped). 
These are the three queries that I am trying to run as mentioned in the tutorial that should change the links in my database:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/Dev_site') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/Dev_site');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.example.com','http://localhost/Dev_site');
```

When I run these queries using PHPmyAdmin nothing happened so I decided to use MySQL Workbench. 
the first query still didn't change anything, but got this:

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

While I know that there it should change something in my table. I removed the last part of the query: `option_name = 'home'`
and got this:

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

One changed!!

the two other queries returned:

Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

I tried to check/uncheck the two first check-boxes in "Preferences -> SQL Queries" as mentioned but It didn't solve my problem.

- Why didn't my first query work the way it is written in the tutorial?
- What can I do to fix the Error I got with the two other queries?
- If it's written in a wrong way, what is the right way to write it?

Edit:

I changed "Preferences -> SQL Queries" as mentioned before, unchecked the second box, closed 'MySQL Workbench' and reopened it, and got:

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 3258  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

When running the second query.

Comment: just to be clear, are you changing `'http://www.example.com'` in your queries to match your actual site domain?

Answer (score 1):

This has sometimes happened to me when trying to run queries on my database using PHPMyAdmin.

There are some plugins on wordpress that may help.

If you want to search and replace the website name to localhost, you can use [Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/).

For arbitrary commands, you can use [SQL Executioner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sql-executioner/).